# Pass the bean to a jar in lib folder

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

We got Java EE 7 project with the following structure:

```
app.ear
  META-INF
    application.xml
  lib
    framework.jar
  webapp.war
  core.jar
```

Framework.jar is our framework that uses some kind of command pattern.

This is how it works. Each command has it's own ejb attached to it that does all the business logic. This command ejb extends CommandEJB class that have an execute method.

For example, this is an example of a command ejb:

```
public class cmdCreateBookEJB<T extends cmdCreateBook> extends CommandEJB<T> {
@Override
public void execute() {
     //do something
}
}
```

And in our framework, we also have CommandExecutorEJB that sets the appropriate ejb for the command and execute it.

Example:

```
CmdCreateBook cmdCreateBook = new cmdCreateBook();
cmdCreateBook.setEjb(cmdCreateBookEJB.class.getSimpleName());
commandExecutorEJB.execute(cmdCreateBook);
```

The problem is our framework, specifically CommandExecutorEJB(that is packed in framework.jar inside lib folder) needs to know about ejb's from core.jar, so it can handle the command. What actually happens in the framework is that the the specific command ejb(cmdCreateBookEJB) in my example is cast to CommandEJB and then it's execute method is called.

The question is how to make the framework know about command ejbs.

I know that one option is to specify am env-entry in ejb-jar.xml with the core jar module name, and then use @Resource in commandExecutorEJB to find the entry, and then use the JNDI lookup to find the resource that would be cast to CommandBean.

But, I would like not to use ejb-jar.xml as we're using ejb 3.2 and ejb-jar.xml isn't necessary anymore.

**EDIT:**
To better explain here is how the jndi lookup string would look like for my example: `java:app/core.jar/cmdCreateBookEJB`

Because framework isn't and shouldn't be aware of the core.jar(The name core.jar name is just an example, someone could name it BookStoreCore.jar), I somehow need to pass module name(in my example core.jar), so that the framework know where to look for classes to find a specific command EJB, in my example cmdCreateBookEJB.

I know that I can use an env-var in ejb-jar.xml to pass module name to the framework. Here's an example:

```
<session>
            <ejb-name>CommandExecutorEJB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>com.mypackage.CommandExecutorEJB</ejb-class>
            <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name>com.mypackage.CommandExecutorEJB/moduleName</env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value>core</env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>
        </session>
```

But, I would love to eliminate ejb-jar.xml from our project setup

Answer (score 0):

You're using Java EE 7.

You can completely avoid class visibility problems by putting everything in your WAR file. `core.jar` and `framework.jar` can both be added to your WEB-INF/lib directory.

You can then directly inject EJBs where ever they're needed.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my problem correctly. Maybe I didn't explain it best. My problem is that framework.jar needs to know about the EJBs that aren't already created. In my example framework doesn't know that cmdCreateBookEJB will be created, but it needs it in order to execute the command. I know I can pass module name of my core in an env-varuable using ejb-jar.xml and then finding the resource by jndi. For example the path would be java:app/core.jar/cmdCreateBookEJB, but I want to avoid that and somehow dynamically inject into the framework, or at least not specify module name

Comment: You have an even more basic problem in that the EJB classes in `core.jar` are not visible to `framework.jar` (unless they are all referenced through interfaces declared in the framework). You need to show more code because I suspect that you need to be exploiting CDI as well.